# Survival Analysis: Error in ggsurvfit(.) : could not find function "ggsurvfit"

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm running the survival analysis in R from the following tutorial: https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html#Part_1:_Introduction_to_Survival_Analysis

I got an error while running the following lines of code to get Kaplan-Meier plots.

```
survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung) %>% 
  ggsurvfit() +
  labs(
    x = "Days",
    y = "Overall survival probability"
  )
```

> Error in ggsurvfit(.) : could not find function "ggsurvfit"

Could anyone help me figure out how to fix the error? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Did you loaded the package? `library(ggsurvfit)`

Comment: I just did and I got this error: Error in library(ggsurvfit) : there is no package called ‘ggsurvfit’ I should install it first though, right? I couldn't find the ggsurvfit package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't downloaded the package, so you can use

```
install.packages("ggsurvfit")
```

or

```
remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/ggsurvfit")
```

*the second command also requires a package (`remotes`).